# Unable to Find an Entry Point (cpp)

Tags: .net, c++, interop

This is a similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385970/unable-to-find-an-entry-point-named-in-dll).

I want to export a simple function from C++, to be called by C# via PInvoke. This is my function definition:

```
 int fnValue()
{
    return 42;
}
```

And this is the export definition in `.h` file:

```
__declspec(dllexport)  int fnValue();
```

This is how I PInvoke the function:

```
    [DllImport("WhatDll.dll")]
    public static extern int fnValue();
```

Simple, right? But I got a

> System.EntryPointNotFoundException :
>   Unable to find an entry 'point named 
>   'fnValue' in DLL "WhatDll.dll'

I use dumpbin to check what's inside `WhatDll`, and this is what I have:

> 00000000 characteristics  4CFB5C95
>   time date stamp Sun Dec 05 17:34:13
>   2010
>        0.00 version
>           1 ordinal base
>           4 number of functions
>           4 number of names
>
> ordinal hint RVA      name
>
> ```
>    1    2 00011014 ?fnValue@@YAHXZ = @ILT+15(?fnValue@@YAHXZ)
> ```

Note that there is some gibberish behind the function name `fnValue`.

This is pretty puzzling. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to write

```
extern "C"__declspec(dllexport)  int fnValue();
```

Comment: @Thanks, any reason why I need `extern "C"` in front?

Comment: Without extern "C" in front the C++ compiler applies "name mangling" or "name decoration" to function names in order to pass more semantic information from the compiler to the linker. extern "C" says to the C++ compiler to avoid mangling references to identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile with a c++ compiler use `extern "C"` to export or add a .def file to specify the export names.
Additionally `__stdcall` might be necessary